# Preventing holder from trading asset

Tags: assets, authorization

From stellar documentation about Control access to assets, I know that there are options can be set for the asset and options to set trustlines for holders.

So, I have a question that: for example I am a issuer and I want to prevent my asset holders from trading my asset for other assets but they could transfer my asset eg: make payment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the authorization required flag on your issuing account and require users to sandwich any operation that affects your asset between a changeTrust (allow) and a changeTrust (deny) operation. This way the user can not perform any transaction without you co-signing.

@see [SEP-0008](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0008.md)